# How can I plot a processmap (bupar) in shiny (R)?

Tags: r, shiny

in my application I want to upload a local csv-file (eventlog), display the datatable and after that create a processmap with the data from the csv-file (bupar). In a normal R-script, the creation of a processmap is working fine. But how can I plot a processmap (below the DataTables) in a shiny application with a button press on the button 'createDiagram'? Thanks in advance!

Below the code:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Visualization"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput("file1", "Choose a File:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      tags$hr(),

      actionButton("createDiagram","Create a Process Diagram"),

      tags$hr()

    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    req(input$file1)

    tryCatch(
      {
        inputData <- read.csv2(input$file1$datapath)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )
  })
}


# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

processmap() outputs a dgr_graph object. These can be rendered in a shiny app with

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grVizOutput(outputId = "process")
```

and

```
output$process <-  renderGrViz({
  plot <- process_map(eventlog, render = F)
  render_graph(plot)
})
```